# Better way to extract elements from a line using perl?

Tags: perl

I want to extract some elements from each line of a file. 
Below is the line:

```
 #                 1150 Reading location  09ef38 data = 00b5eda4
```

I would like to extract the address **09ef38** and the data **00b5eda4** from this line.

The way I use is the simple one like below:

```
while($line = < INFILE >) {

    if ($line =~ /\#\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*=\s*(\S+)/) {
       $time = $1;
       $address = $4;
       $data = $6;
       printf(OUTFILE "%s,%s,%s \n",$time,$address,$data);
      }
}
```

I am wondering is there any better idea to do this ? easier and cleaner?

Thanks a lot!

TCGG

Comment: Better provides a sample input & output...

Comment: Do your lines always have this format: "Reading location 09ef38 data = 00b5eda4"?

Comment: Hi sputnick, thanks for the comment. What do you mean a sample input & output?

Comment: Hi Kenosis, not always like "Reading location ...", sometimes there is "Writing location...."

Comment: Paste about 10 lines of sample input into the body of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to [split](http://p3rl.org/split) the string on whitespace:

```
my ($time, $addr, $data) = (split / +/, $line)[1, 4, 7];
```

Comment: One question, if I want to find/locate the $line first, how can I use this way?  I still need the if statement, right?

Comment: @TCGG: If you cannot detect the line by something simpler (`next unless index $line, ' data = '`), the regex is probably the way to go. You can still match and assign in one place: `if (my ($time, $addr, $data) = $line =~ /$regex/) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use matching and a list on LHS, something likes this:

```
echo '# 1150 Reading location 09ef38 data = 00b5eda4' | 
  perl -ne '
    $,="\n";
    ($time, $addr, $data) = /#\s+(\w+).*?location\s+(\w+).*?data\s*=\s*(\w+)/;
    print $time, $addr, $data'
```

Output:

```
1150
09ef38
00b5eda4
```

Answer (score 0):

In python the appropriate regex will be like:

```
'[0-9]+[a-zA-Z ]*([0-9]+[a-z]+[0-9]+)[a-zA-Z ]*= ([0-9a-zA-Z]+)'
```

But I don't know exactly how to write it in perl. You can search for it. If you need any explanation of this regexp, I can edit this post with more precise description.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. python is interesting too.

Comment: Thor has the shot though :D I thought they would be similar, but apparently perl regexps are more powerful than python ones, as it is said in books :)

Answer (score 0):

I find it convenient to just split by one or more whitespaces of any kind, using `\s+`. This way you won't have any problems if the input string has any tab characters in it instead of spaces.

```
while($line = <INFILE>)
{
    my ($time, $addr, $data) = (split /\s+/, $line)[1, 4, 7];
}
```

When splitting by ANY kind of whitespace it's important to note that it'll also split by the newline at the end, so you'll get an empty element at the end of the return. But in most cases, unless you care about the total amount of elements returned, there's no need to care.

Comment: yep, that's exactly what choroba has proposed . Really good idea. thx